# Is there a rigorous proof for this beautiful property of the function of type $f(x) \sin x$?

Tags: proof-writing, graphing-functions

I just noticed today that the graph of $x \sin x$ is like a $\sin x$ trapped in $x$ and $-x$. Upon this realisation, I tried to plot some graphs by hand, others by desmos. I tried to investigate this property according to which always $\sin x$ would be trapped inside the $+f(x)$ and $-f(x)$ for a function $g(x)=f(x) \sin x$ and its shape would change in order to fit the function at varying x coordinates. But, rather than doing induction I wanted to prove that this type of property will always be valid.

 I defined a function;
$$g(x) = f(x) \sin x$$
$$-f(x)\le g(x) \le f(x)$$
$$-1 \le \sin x\le 1$$
Now we can argue that $f(x)$ will act like a varying amplitude for $\sin x$ wave(/graph) and thus it should be trapped. But this is not satisfactory enough.
**Thus my question is, “Is there a rigorous proof for this sort of property?”**

---

Following are the graphs I tried to analyse the property off of:

### 1. $x \cdot \sin x$

[image]

### 2. $x^2 \sin x$

[image]

### 3. $x^3 \sin x$

[image]

### 4. $\frac{\sin x}{x^2+1}$

[image]

### 5. $\ln x \cdot \sin x$

[image]

### 6. $(3x^2-2x^3) \sin x$

[image]

### 7. $((1-x^{\frac{2}3})^{\frac{3}2}) \sin x$

[image]

### 8. $\sqrt{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)} \cdot \sin x $

[image]

### 9. $x \sqrt{\frac{x+5}{x-5}} \cdot \sin x $

[image]

Comment: What *exactly* are you asking or? A proof of f $-1 \le \sin(x) \le 1$?

Comment: @MartinR *Thus my question is, “Is there a rigorous proof for this sort of property?”*

Comment: What is your definition of $\sin(x)$ ?

Comment: This is the "**envelope** property" which is very important in **signal processing**, the signal is said **modulated**. Besides you have too much drawings... the last ones not being very informative... The 3 first ones are enough.

Comment: @PaxDaga *What is your definition of sin(x)?* That's a interesting question, Well, here it goes. sinx is a function defined for the entire real number line(pun intended) which is periodic with period $2 \pi$ and is an odd function. Or there is another basic right triangle definition which we all know.

Comment: @JeanMarie I did think that it might be related to modulation but I did not know it had a name. I drew the rest graphs for graphical analysis and also because some of them rather looked beautiful. :=)

Comment: @PM2Ring Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that $\sin(x)$ is bounded, indeed $|\sin(x)|\leq 1$. This gives us: $$|f(x)\sin(x)|\leq|f(x)|\cdot|\sin(x)|\leq|f(x)|\cdot 1=|f(x)|.$$
In other words, an element of $g(x)$ can never go above the graph of $f(x)$ or below the graph of $-f(x)$. Can you try to generalize this for a function $h(x)$ such that $|h(x)|\leq n$ for $n$ a natural number? What would happen to the graph of $h(x)f(x)$?

Comment: Thanks(+1) *Can you try to generalize this for a function h(x) such that |h(x)|≤n for n a natural number? What would happen to the graph of h(x)f(x)?* Thanks for the generalisation, I did just realise and plot a few graphs in desmos, to realise that any such function will get trapped. for example ${\frac{2x e^x}{1+x^2}}$

Comment: Using the same argument you see that it would get trapped in $n$ times the function $f(x)$ right?